# PHP - Including Multiple Xpath Variables in the Same Foreach Loop

Tags: php, xpath, foreach, domdocument

I found this great code which is helping me parse through and display results from a php generated html table on another page on my server, using PHP's DOMDocument and DOMXpath:

```
$my_url = 'http://example.com/htmltable.php';
$html = file_get_contents($my_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$my_xpath_query = "//iframe/@src";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);

foreach ($result_rows as $result_object){
    echo '<li>' . $result_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . '</li>';

}
```

The problem is, I want to add another variable to the same foreach loop, something like this:

```
$my_url = 'http://example.com/htmltable.php';
$html = file_get_contents($my_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$my_xpath_query = "//iframe/@src";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);

$my_xpath_queryB = "//a/@href";
$result_rowsB = $xpath->query($my_xpath_queryB);

foreach ($result_rows as $result_object && $result_rowsB as $result_objectB){
    echo '<li>' . $result_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . '</li><li>' . $result_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . '</li>';

}
```

This code is not working, and I've done a bit of research also, which has lead me to believe that including multiple variables in the same foreach loop is not possible. Can anyone verify this, and if so, does anyone have another idea for how I could achieve a similar result?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try `$merged = array_merge($result_rows,$result_rowsB); ` and use $merged in the foreach.

Comment: these two queries can return results of different length. What to do in the case?

Comment: `array_merge` merges arrays nothing more, so you dont have to use same size arrays  e.g. `array_merge([1],[2,3])` becomes `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thanks for your reply! Okay I'm using this now, but still not working, what am I missing? 

`$merged = array_merge($result_rows, $result_rowsB);

foreach ($merged as $mergedB){
  echo '<li>' . $mergedB[0]->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . '</li><li>' . $mergedB[1]->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . '</li>';
 
}`

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is that the xpath->query variables are not arrays, but DOMNodeList Objects... trying to figure out how to work around this.

Comment: Maybe, XML is a little tricky in PHP ::)))

Comment: out of curiosity: if that page you are parsing is on your own server, wouldn't it be easier to just get the data pieces you want from your database or wherever it comes from? where does htmltables.php get the href and src values from?

Comment: and also: your currently deleted answer is correct **if** you really have to do this by parsing the html output.